# Are these two piecewise functions the same function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary sets, and let $Z$ be a strict subset of $X$. Then, define a function $f:X\to Y$ as follows:
\begin{gather}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
    a&\text{if }x\in Z\\
    b&\text{else}
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
Further, define the function $g:X\to Y$ as follows:
\begin{gather}
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
    a&\text{if and only if }x\in Z\\
    b&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
Are these two piece-wise functions identical or are they different? In other words, can I interchange "if/else" for "if and only if/otherwise"?

Thank you all very much for your time.

Comment: They’re the same as long as $a \neq b$.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment. Suppose $a=b$. What happens then?

Comment: If $a=b$ and $Z \neq X$, then $g$ is not well defined. If $g(x) = a$, by the only-if condition it follows that $x \in Z$. However, since $Z \neq X$ and $a=b$, we can produce $x \notin Z$ so that $g(x)=a$. This contradicts the definition of $g$.

Comment: Thank you again for your comment. I understand that "if" and "iff" are not interchangeable. Are "else" and "otherwise" completely interchangeable?

Comment: They’re basically interchangable, insofar as they can be interpreted to mean the same logical dependency. Some people might split hairs, but I read them as the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a convoluted way, the functions are not exactly the same !
By making a simple change, the functions can become same !

In one $f(x)$ has 2 values : $a , b$ but we can even choose $a=b$

In the other $g(x)$ also has 2 values: $a , b$, but we can not choose $a=b$ because of the "if & only if".

We can make a simple change to exclude $a = b$ ; then the functions are exactly same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that "if" and "iff" are not interchangeable. Are "else" and "otherwise" completely interchangeable?

Comment: Yes , "If/Else" is completely interchangeable with "If/Otherwise" ;; "Iff/Else" is completely interchangeable with "Iff/Otherwise" ;; No change in meaning !

Comment: Thank you for your useful comment. So, only the distinction between if and iff matters, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the "core".